# Android / kotlin - TabLayout with shared inputs

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I create a `TabLayout` that shares an `input`? is this possible?
I want to fill the data in both tabs at the same time.

And, if the user clicks on a record of the tabs; it should open another control that I've already created, filling it with the data of the selected record.

I can't post images, so I hope this helps:

**Title:** Pending Moves

**Inputs:**

| Warehouse : | [Spinner] |
| --- | --- |
| Show cancelled bills: | [x] |

**TabLayout:**

| Departure by transfer | Departure by customer delivery |
| --- | --- |

**Datatable for both tab options:**

| Id | Request Date | etc |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: you can use live data/obervable concept so that you can have multiple subscriber to one observable to listen and will fill the data everywhere it will be subscribing.

Comment: you can check here for example : https://www.baeldung.com/rxjava-multiple-subscribers-observable